# Understand the shape in tf.keras.Input?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input, shapes, dimension

I just learn tensorflow and keras. Here is a code example:

```
# Create a symbolic input
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.float32)

# Do a calculation using is
result = 2*input + 1

# the result doesn't have a value
result

calc = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=result)
print(calc(np.array([1,2,3,4])).numpy())
print(calc(2).numpy())
```

The document says shape: A shape tuple (integers), not including the batch size.
For instance, `shape=(32,)` indicates that the expected input will be batches of 32-dimensional vectors. Elements of this tuple can be `None`; `None` elements represent dimensions where the shape is not known.

But in the above code, two print lines both work. But for me, they are `1D` dimensions and 1 scalar. So how do understand the shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is `tf. keras.Input` produces symbolic tensor or placeholders. And it can be used with the `TF` operation. See in the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py#L266):

```
  Note that even if eager execution is enabled,
  `Input` produces a symbolic tensor (i.e. a placeholder).
  This symbolic tensor can be used with other
  TensorFlow ops, as such:
  '''python
  x = Input(shape=(32,))
  y = tf.square(x)
  '''
```

That's why those print lines both work.

---

Now, here are some scenarios. In your code, you can set `shape = [n]` where `n > = 0`, for rank `0` and `1` which are scaler and vector respectively. But you will get an error for rank `2` or matrix if `n` is not equal to `x.shape[1]`. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

# Create a symbolic input
input  = tf.keras.Input(shape=[0], dtype=tf.float32)
result = 2*input + 1 
calc   = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=result)

print(calc(1).numpy())                     # scaler rank 0
print(calc(np.array([1,2,3,4])).numpy())   # vector rank 1
print(calc(np.array([[1,2,3,4]])).numpy()) # matrix rank 2
```

```
3.0
[3. 5. 7. 9.]

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: 
expected shape=(None, 0), found shape=(1, 4)
```

To solve it we need to set an exact number of feature dimensions to the shape parameter, here which should be `4`.

```
# Create a symbolic input
input  = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4], dtype=tf.float32)
result = 2*input + 1 
calc   = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=result)

print(calc(1).numpy())                     # scaler rank 0
print(calc(np.array([1,2,3,4])).numpy())   # vector rank 1
print(calc(np.array([[1,2,3,4]])).numpy()) # matrix rank 2
```

```
3.0
[3. 5. 7. 9.]
[[3. 5. 7. 9.]]
```

Here is one interesting fact, if we build this `calc` model with `shape = [1]` with scalar or vector and **followed by** `2D` matrix, it won't raise any complaint about `2D` input because it would raise an error only if the model didn't build firstly. By invoking the model with some input, the shape of the model gets set.

```
# Create a symbolic input
input  = tf.keras.Input(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)
result = 2*input + 1 
calc   = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=result)

print(calc(1).numpy())                     # scaler rank 0
print(calc(np.array([1,2,3,4])).numpy())   # vector rank 1
print(calc(np.array([[1,2,3,4]])).numpy()) # matrix rank 2
```

```
3.0
[[3.]
 [5.]
 [7.]
 [9.]]
[[3. 5. 7. 9.]]
```

---

But AFAIK, it won't possible to play around like this if you build a model with a trainable layer. In that case, you need to ensure the shape matching issue between `shape` and the input data. For example:

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4])
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)

print(model(np.array([[1,2,3,4]])).numpy()) # (1, 4)
print(model(np.array([1,2,3,4])).numpy())   # (4,)
```

```
[[ 1.4779348  -1.8168153  -0.93788755 -1.4927139  -0.23618054  2.4305463
  -1.6176091   0.6640817  -1.648994    3.5819988 ]]

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: 
: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (4,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that your "model" will fail if you are going to compile and try `fit` it, because there is nothing to 'learn'.

However: It seams that for simple operations such as `2*input + 1` the shape is not relevant, as the model does not contain any neural network nodes, so it does not establish weight and bias matrices, which would require a shape to be known.

So you are right in the respect that you shouldn't expect a model which input shape is `(2,)` to accept neither scalars nor vectors of shape `(4,)` - and it wouldn't, once you have added some neural network layers, such as `keras.layers.Dense()` or comparable.

Comment: Why is the input_shape often written as (2,) with that comma and nothing after it?
Why not just (2)?

Comment: @skan That is a tuple. (2) would just be 2. (2,) is a tuple with one element.

Comment: but both (2) and (2,) give the same result here.
Anyway, why use a tuple leaving the last element empty?